# Automorphism groups and symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Looking on the Wikipedia page for [automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism); in the examples it first states that in set theory, the automorphism of a set $X$ is an arbitrary permutation of the elements of $X$, and these form the automorphism group, also known as the symmetric group, on $X$. However on the page [Automorphisms of the symmetric and alternating groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups), $ \operatorname{Aut}(S_n) = S_n $ except in the cases where $n=1,2,6$. So is the statement on the automorphism page incorrect when it says that all automorphism groups on $X$ are also known as symmetric groups, as not all of them are when for example $X=S_n$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Automorphism of a **set** is an arbitrary permutation of its elements. An automorphism of a **group** is permutation of its elements which preserves the operation, i.e. $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$. Since every group $G$ is a set, you can look at two possible automorphism groups: one - $\operatorname{Aut}_{Set}(G)$ as a set and the other $\operatorname{Aut}_{Gp}(G)$ as a group. Cleraly $\operatorname{Aut}_{Gp}(G)\leq \operatorname{Aut}_{Set}(G)$, but usually they are not equal.
When talking about groups, the notion $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ means the set of group-automorphism of $G$.
In your case, $\operatorname{Aut}(S_n)$ denotes the **group-automorphisms** of $S_n$, so there is no contradiction with the previous statements. 
BTW, there is no problem with $n=1$, since $S_1=\{id\}$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(S_1)=\{id\}$.
To illustrate the problem in $S_2=\{id,(1,2)\}$, observe that there are two automorphisms of $S_2$ as a set:
$$\begin{array}{c}id\mapsto id\\ (1,2)\mapsto(1,2)\end{array} \hspace{10pt} {\rm{and}}\hspace{10pt}\begin{align*}id &\mapsto (1,2)\\ (1,2)&\mapsto id\end{align*}$$
but the right automorphism is *not* a group-automorphism, hence there exists only one group-automorphism of $S_2$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks

Answer (score 3):

In general, an automorphism of an *object* $A$ is a *morphism* $f\colon A\to A$ such that there exists a morphism $g\colon A\to A$ such that the composositions $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both the identity morphism of $A$.

To step from this abstract concept to some concrete situation, one must specify what kind of *objects* one talks about and what a *morphism* is. For sets (or as one says: in the category **Set**), an object is, of course, just a set and a morphism is simply a map. Then an automorphism of a set $A$ is simply an arbitrary bijective map $A\to A$.

On the other hand, for groups (in the category **Grp**), the objects are groups and the morphisms are *group homomorphisms*, i.e. maps that "respect the group law". For example, an automorphism of a group necessarily maps the identity element to itself, whereas a bijection (or "set-automorphism") need not obey this restriction.

Comment: That's very helpful to know the general use of the term, thanks

Comment: I would also accept your answer, but unfortunately it only lets you select one?

Comment: Rereading the answer, should it not be the compositions $f \circ B$ and $B \circ f$ that are both the identity morphism of $A$?

Comment: @SJGreen Thanks, I corrected. No idea why I wanted to call the inverse $B$ in the first place. :)